AWS Route 53: cost of having a subdomain on another DNS provider than AWS
I got an issue with AWS Route 53 costs, because I was previously running a DNSBL service (back when my domain was on another DNS provider). This service is long gone, but people still query my blacklist DNS record. This increases my AWS bill uncontrollably. I do not know who still "uses" my blacklist.
I tried to raise TTLs as high as possible for the relevant A/TXT records. This helps a bit, but not enough.
Now my other idea is to delegate this subdomain that I used for the DNSBL to another provider that doesn't charge me for DNS queries. So adding NS records for rbl.example.org and pointing them to a non-AWS DNS provider. I cannot find this setup in the Route 53 pricing page. Any idea if there are even costs associated with such a setup?


So adding NS records for rbl.example.org and pointing them to a non-AWS DNS provider. I cannot find this setup in the Route 53 pricing page. Any idea if there are even costs associated with such a setup?

There is no additional cost associated with this. To AWS, this is just some more DNS records in your Route53 zone. The only real cost would be from the DNS queries for the subdomain.

Sorry, that was my actual question, i.e. is it economically more useful to outsource that subdomain, or is it resulting in the same charge anyways.

The subdomain queries should be cached better than your A/TXT records, but that is really ultimately up to whoever is doing all those DNS queries against your domain. I would honestly recommend just moving away from Route53 to something like Cloudflare that has a better pricing model.

I'm currently using an ALIAS record to redirect to a Cloudfront distribution (with an unreachable S3 bucket as backend) which doesn't cost me anything. I'm currently evaluating which workaround is less nasty.
